# Build failed: Cannot find module react-native/local-cli/cli.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
throw err;
^
Cannot find module  android/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js'

1)I am not using react-native-community/cli

How can i fix this?

Comment: What are you using if not cli?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.